# How do I get the oauth token after logging into Twitter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, oauth

After logging into Twitter, I am able to print out some useful data such as the username and user ID. However, the OAuth token is always null. How do I get it? I need to send OAuth token to my server so it can verify that the user is indeed who he says he is.

```
ACAccountStore* accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType* twitterType = [self.context.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[accountStore
    requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType
    withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL isAllowed, NSError* error) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            if (isAllowed) {
                ACAccount* account = [[self.context.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:[self.context.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter]] lastObject];
                NSLog(@"username = %@", account.username);
                NSLog(@"user_id = %@", [[account valueForKey:@"properties"] valueForKey:@"user_id"]);
                // ouath token is always null
                NSLog(@"oauth token = %@", account.credential.oauthToken);
            }
        });
    }
];
```

I "*think*" I need [Reverse Auth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth), but that tutorial mysteriously left out the code for "step 1".

Comment: NSLog(@"oauth token = %@", account.credential.oauthToken); here i get6 the null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will indeed need to use Reverse Auth.

I recently used [Sean Cook's TWReverseAuth](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample) and it worked very well. Just be careful to turn off ARC for the individual files in the `Vendor` directory.

Comment: It's strange how the docs say it's ARC ready, but when I read the code, there were many release and autorelease.