# Is it possible to get oauth token when requesting access to Facebook via Accounts framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to do make some API calls in the background on the server that's why I need the oauth token.

Using `ACAccountCredential`'s `oauthToken` method, it returns `null`. My question is, it it possible to somehow get the oauth token?

For example Instagram does this. They authenticate via Accounts framework and send the token to their servers where they do all the graph API calls.

Thanks

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713472/how-do-i-get-the-oauth-token-after-logging-into-twitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited to address @0xSina's comment)

Yes.  I understand that you've tried accessing the oauthToken property of the `ACAccountCredential`, of the Facebook ACAccount object and that it is returning nil.  That said, this IS the way to do it and it does not return `nil` when everything is set up correctly.

I created a test project to prove this and the relevant code is below.  A few things to check:

1) on your Facebook app information page, ensure that you have your bundle ID set in the Native iOS App section.

2) (pretty obviously) make sure you have your Facebook account setup in iOS settings.

3) if you can't get your main project to work, try an empty test project, as I did, and see if that works.  You'll have to remember to set your test project's bundleID to match what you entered on the Facebook settings page!

Here's the code with some asserts to notify you if something's failing:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ACAccountStore* as = [ACAccountStore new];

    ACAccountType* fbat = [as accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSAssert( fbat != nil, @"oops, can't find account-type for facebook!");

    [as requestAccessToAccountsWithType: fbat

                                options: @{ ACFacebookAppIdKey : @"99999999999", // your FB appid here!
                                            ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[ @"email" ] }

                             completion: ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

                                 NSAssert( granted && error==nil, @"oops, access not granted!");

                                 if ( granted )
                                 {
                                     NSArray* accounts = [as accountsWithAccountType: fbat];
                                     NSAssert( accounts.count > 0, @"oops, no accounts??" );

                                     ACAccount* fbaccount = [accounts lastObject];

                                     ACAccountCredential* ac = [fbaccount credential];
                                     NSAssert( ac != nil, @"oops, no credential??" );

                                     NSString* token = [ac oauthToken];
                                     NSAssert( token.length > 0, @"oops, no credential??" );

                                     NSLog( @"token=%@", token );
                                 }
                             }];


}
```

One common issue, I think, is to mis-format the `ACFacebookPermissionsKey` as a string instead of an array of strings.  Or to forego it altogether because the docs say it is optional (it isn't.)

And, here's the output from my test (slightly altered so I'm not publishing a real token here)

```
2013-07-26 16:54:23.699 testfb[26870:1303] token=CAAAAEZBYxezsBAK6OK9YPQIfA0GjiG7rn2XjdZBC6lZCpfAAAocr2cyEnmne9eMh59ZA4UabQyZAsdQMu0gMruxEJXJI1tFfBVTmLqNpRK31GPQvr3rXRAr50HUXI37iS46gPwXwZAroUHT7WqZCza6HcV6L35gVThBcOttWNxozj1df70XluEreM14nucSmvimjVGu5i4ZBZAUrSYLsvO
```

Comment: If you read my question, it says: Using ACAccountCredential's oauthToken method, it returns null. And I've seen that question before. In the answer of question you linked: "Unfortunately we can't use [self.fbAccount credential]; - this method return null - just look at docs"

Comment: @0xSina - I did read your question carefully.  I think something else is wrong in your app that is causing the token to return nil.  Please try my updated code in an empty sample app - if it still fails then I can try posting my complete sample project for you.

Comment: my apologies, maybe i am wrong...just frustrated with this problem...  I will update my question with complete source code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that sometimes, either due to one's development process or timed expiration, the Facebook credentials for an app can become invalid. At this point, calls to `account.credential` will return invalid or nil. In this case you must renew the credential. To do this, simply call `-renewCredentialsForAccount:completion:` on the account in question. For Facebook accounts this will renew the oauth token automatically.

For other service types the user may be prompted for their password, check the docs in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue. The problem for me was that I was setting my Facebook account in the completion handler of: `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` and then attempting to access the `ACAccountCredential` in a different function.

Getting the oauth token in the completion handler and saving it for later solved the problem for me:

```
[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:options completion:
    ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        ...    
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            facebookAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];
            oAuthToken = facebookAccount.credential.oauthToken;
        });
        ...
    }
];
```